# Given $U,v,w$ find $u \in U$ that value of $||u-w|| + || v - u||$ will be minimal

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $U,v,w$

> $ U = \{ x \in R^3 | x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0 \}, v = \frac{1}{3}[10,-2,-2]^T, w = [8,1,-5]^T$

find $u \in U$ that value of $||u-w|| + || v - u||$ will be minimal.

I believe that for minimal value, $u$ must be the projection vector in sub space $U$.

we know that $n = [1,1,1]^T$, and to find $u$ we need to solve $A^TAx = A^Tu$ and thus $Ax = u = p$ and if $p = u$ then $||u-w|| + || v - u||$ will be minimal.

What do you think?

Comment: which norm are you considering here ? Is it the $l^2$, Euclidean norm ($||(x,y,z)||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$) ?

Comment: and are you sure it is asked to minimize $\|u-w\|+\|v-u\|$ and not $\|u-w\|^2+\|v-u\|^2$ ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yes, that one.

Comment: @user1952009 I am sure.

Comment: There is a one-line complete answer : By the triangle inequality, $||v-u||+||u-w|| \geq ||v-w||$ with equality iff $u$ is a convex combination of $u$ and $v$. No wonder people like user1592009 are surprised by your question

Comment: @EwanDelanoy : and $U$ contains such a $u = \alpha v + (1-\alpha) w$ for $\alpha = \ldots$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I still don't understand  your answer, and how to find that $u$

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS You might want to look up the words you don't understand in Google/Wikipedia/whatever, or ask about them here. user1952009 has also added a little bit of additional help for you above

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the situation is a little bit more complicated than I thought, I finally included an answer

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the line joining $v$ to $w$, so that $D=\lbrace \alpha v+(1-\alpha)w | \alpha\in{\mathbb R}\rbrace$. Given any $u\in U$, we can project $u$ orthogonally onto $D$, writing $u=d+e$ where  $d\in D$ and $e$ is orthogonal to $w-v$.

Then, using Pythagoras' theorem (and putting $f(u)=||u-w||+||v-u||$),

$$
f(u)=\sqrt{||u-d||^2+||d-w||^2}+\sqrt{||u-d||^2+||d-v||^2} \geq \sqrt{||d-w||^2}+\sqrt{||d-v||^2} =f(d)
$$

So $f$ is minimal when $u$ coincides with $d$. The unique solution to your problem is therefore the point at the intersection of $D$ with $U$.